# Количество запущенных Task

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, tpl

Запускаю около 50 задач (Task). Задачи выполняются с разной скоростью.

Мне надо **выводить в WPF контрол количество работающих задач**.

Как я понимаю должен быть счетчик, который `++` при запуске задачи, и `--` при завершении задачи. Как только счетчик станет `== 0`, надо вызвать определенный метод.

По идее для такого сценария должно быть готовое решение, но ничего подходящего не нашел. Единственное что приходит на ум, сделать счетчик `int count = 0;` и `object countLock = new Object();` и менять значение `count` из разных задач примерно так `lock(countLock) count++;`. 
Но мне кажется, что есть лучшее решение?

**Примечание:** задачи запускаются не все сразу, а очередями. Несколько запустились, пауза, еще несколько запустились, пауза. В это время часть задач может завершиться, и еще несколько запуститься.

Comment: так вроде [WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) - именно так и работает?

Comment: А как из WhenAll выводить количество оставшихся задач на экран?

Answer (score 4):

Например, так.

```
List<Task> tasks = // ваши 50 task'ов

RemainingTasks = tasks.Count;
List<Task> augmentedTasks = tasks.Select(async t => { await t; RemainingTasks--; }).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(augmentedTasks);
// здесь все 50 завершились
```

(Разумеется, это должно быть в async-методе, и быть запущенным в UI-потоке.)

Если `RemainingTasks` — свойство в VM с `INotifyPropertyChanged`, к нему можно привязать контрол в UI. Ну или если вы почему-то ещё не пользуетесь MVVM, и делаете всё в OnClick (о ужас!), можно завести dependency property.

---

Если у вас задачи добавляются пачками, то и изменять счётчик нужно пачками.

```
async Task CreateTasks()
{
    List<Task> tasks = // создаёте здесь новые Task'и как вам хочется
    RemainingTasks += tasks.Count;
    List<Task> augmentedTasks =
        tasks.Select(async t => { await t; RemainingTasks--; }).ToList();
    await Task.WhenAll(augmentedTasks);
    // здесь все *добавленные* Task'и отработали, и вы можете сделать
    // что-то ещё. но может быть, что тем временем другой вызов CreateTasks()
    // создал ещё, так что в этой точке RemainingTasks не обязательно 0
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35848/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---task).

Answer (score 1):

Держите:

```
public class BackgroundTaskManager : GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase {
    private int activeTasks;

    public int ActiveTasks {
      get { return activeTasks; }
      set { base.Set("ActiveTasks", ref activeTasks, value) }
    }

    public IDisposable StartTask() {
      ActiveTasks++;
      return new TaskToken(this);
    }

    private class TaskToken : IDisposable {
      private readonly BackgroundTaskManager owner;
      public TaskToken(BackgroundTaskManager owner) { this.owner = owner; }

      public void Dispose() {
        owner.ActiveTasks--;
      }
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
async void SomeAction() {
  using (bgtm.StartTask()) {
    await ...;
  }
}
```

Этот метод подсчитывает подготовленные к подсчету задачи, создаваемые в потоке UI. По-хорошему, тут надо еще Assertов добавить, но я забыл как проверить что текущий поток - это поток UI.

Comment: А GalaSoft я могу использовать и где мне взять этот класс?

Comment: В соответствующем [пакете](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/) nuget

Comment: А насколько правильно не соблюдать паттерн Dispose, который приводится в документации https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx Надо ли мне добавить код из Basic Dispose Pattern или можно оставить как в ответе?

Comment: Нет, не надо. Даже нельзя. В данном случае все построено на том, что доступ к свойству `ActiveTasks` всегда будет идти из одного и того же потока - но для финализатора это правило нарушится.