# как в с# узнать список не завершенных Task' ов?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Программа на c# запускает много асинхронных Task'ов. Как получить их список для того чтобы дождаться из завершения (Task.WhenAny)?

Спасибо.

Comment: А зачем вам? Расскажите вашу задачу поподробнее.

Comment: если при запуске они никуда не складываются то никак

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493894/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-task

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520926/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-threadpool-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938999/sort-tasks-into-order-of-completition

Comment: Это не полные дубликаты - но там можно увидеть что-то полезное.

Comment: Спасибо всем откликнувшимся. Сегодня просмотрю ваши ответы по-подробней. Пока меня привлек метод async Task processClient из http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/336949/. Но хотелось бы найти список активных задач в недрах самой CLR. Меньше месяца назад, кажется, наталкивался на такую информацию. Там LINQ запросом из метаданных извлекался список активных Task'ов или thread'ов.